# browse files in google team drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to write a simple Google Apps Script to list the files in a Google Team Drive and I am not having much success.

Here is the code:

```js
function start()
{
  Logger.log("Starting application...");
  var startingFolders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Temp");
  if (startingFolders.hasNext())
  {
    // Assuming only one folder with that name
    accessFiles(startingFolders.next());
  }
  else
    Logger.log("Folder not found");
}

function accessFiles(folder)
{
  Logger.log("Folder: %s", folder.getName());
  // Print some file properties
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log("Working on file %s. Current access: %s.", file.getName(), file.getSharingAccess());
    // some work here...
  }

  // Explore subfolders
  while (folder.hasNext())
  {
    var subfolder = folder.next();
    accessFiles(subfolder);
  }
}
```

The problem is that the log always prints the "Folder not found" message. "Temp" is a folder in a **Team Drive** that I have Full access to. Note that I am trying to use the Google Apps Script and not the REST API.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or if Team Drives are not supported yet...

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I don't recall anyone mentioning that it's supported yet. Another option is that it could be supported, but scripts from a users drive cannot reach a team drive. Is your script located in the same team drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to search file and folders on a Team Drive by using the Google apps Script Service (DriveApp) but we could use the Drive Advanced Service but first we should enabled it first. The instructions are on [Enabling Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

The following script will list all the files inside a folder named Temp from an specified Team Drive by its id.

```
function listFiles(){
  var teamDriveId = 'put_here_the_teamdrive_id';
  var pageToken;
  var folders = Drive.Files.list({  
    corpora: 'teamDrive',
    supportsTeamDrives: true,
    teamDriveId: teamDriveId,
    includeTeamDriveItems: true,
    q: 'title = "Temp"'
  });
  if(folders.items.length !== 1) {
    Logger.log('There is a problem.');
    return;
  }
  var query = 'trashed = false and ' + //to exclude trashed files
      'not mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"'; // To exclude folders
  var files, pageToken;
  do {
    files = Drive.Files.list({
      q: query,
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken,
      // required for team drive queries
      corpora: 'teamDrive',
      supportsTeamDrives: true,
      teamDriveId: teamDriveId,
      includeTeamDriveItems: true
    });
    if (files.items && files.items.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < files.items.length; i++) {
        var file = files.items[i];
        Logger.log('%s (ID: %s)', file.title, file.id);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No files found.');
    }
    pageToken = files.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Rubén, this is exactly what I was trying to do! No need for a recursive search anymore with this type of sql-like query!